# how can i fix 'failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

so i have a index for my map points and i need to put some data in it. but it seems it does not register my data as a valid input for pin.location .

I have tried all i could get from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html
and still this does not work

This is where i set the index:

```py
mappings = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "pin": {
                "properties": {
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            },
            "index.mapping.single_type": False
        }
    }
}
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
if not es.indices.exists(index="groups_map"):
    es.indices.create(index='groups_map', body=mappings)
es.index(index='groups_map', id=data["id"], doc_type='groups_map', body=data, request_timeout=30)
```

here is data:

```py
data = {
        "pin": {
               "properties": {"location": {
                              "type": "geo_point",
                              'lat': request.POST['source_lat'],
                              'lon': request.POST['source_lon']}
                    }

                },
         "id": instance.id,

        }
```

and this is my query data here is just a dictionary with lat and lon values

```py
 query = {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "12km",
                    "pin.location": {
                        "lat": data["lat"],
                        "lon": data["lon"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
return es.search(index="groups_map", body={"query": query}, size=20)
```

this is the full error i get:
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]')

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-geo-point-type.html

Comment: @LinPy i get this error :
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [pin : {properties={location={type=geo_point}}}]')

Comment: ```
mappings = {
    "mappings": {
        "pin": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not correct as you need to remove the `properties` key. Your data should look like this.

```
data = {
    "pin": {
         "location": {
               'lat': request.POST['source_lat'],
               'lon': request.POST['source_lon']
         }
    },
    "id": instance.id,
}
```

Note: You need to delete and recreate your index before indexing new data.

Comment: I changed the data to what you said but I am still getting the message:
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]')

Comment: You need to delete the index and recreate it first.

Comment: i did that too with this curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/groups_map"

Comment: Ok, then can you show what you get when running `curl -XGET "localhost:9200/groups_map"` after you've run your code?

Comment: before deleting :{"groups_map":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long"},"pin":{"properties":{"location":{"properties":{"lat":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"lon":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1567069163611","number_of_shards":"1","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"Gp4hdzxGTpmINEbxGBDCUQ","version":{"created":"7030199"},"provided_name":"groups_map"}}}}%

Comment: after deleting : 
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [groups_map]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"groups_map","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"groups_map"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [groups_map]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"groups_map","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"groups_map"},"status":404}%

Comment: Ok, can you run your code but without the last line `es.index(...)` and then run `curl -XGET "localhost:9200/groups_map"` again please

Comment: {"groups_map":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"properties":{"pin":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point"}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1567073843387","number_of_shards":"1","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"5g7SSukkQC6Juru1a6_oXg","version":{"created":"7030199"},"provided_name":"groups_map"}}}}%

Comment: Looks much better now. Now you should be able to call `es.index(...)` but look at my updated answer, in the data you need to remove the `type` field in `pin.location`.

Comment: still no luck :
 RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Rejecting mapping update to [groups_map] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, groups_map]'

Comment: either remove `doc_type='groups_map'` or replace with `doc_type='_doc'`

Comment: changing to `doc_type='_doc'` actually worked thank you